# I want to ingnore a blank cell using the 360 formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the fx =IF(DAYS360(H4,TODAY())<1,"Not overdue",DAYS360(H4,TODAY())) however I want to ignore it if the ref cell is blank. I've tried various options without success. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping it in an if() statement:

```
=IF(H4<>"",IF(DAYS360(H4,TODAY())<1,"Not overdue",DAYS360(H4,TODAY())),"error")
```

I assumed H4 was the cell to check if it was blank.